# json to json conversion by ExecuteScript processor

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have following json data and i want to convert data in expected result by ExecuteScript nifi processor

```json
{
"time": "2017-01-01T01:14:55+00:00",
"any": {
"nested": "data"
}
}
```

expected Result

```json
{
"time": 1483233295,
"any": {
"nested": "data"
}
}
```

I am using following groovy code but getting some error please help to find the solution

```
var flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile !== null) {

var StreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback");
var IOUtils = Java.type("org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new 
        StreamCallback(function(inputStream, outputStream) {

var inputJSON = IOUtils.toString(inputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
var contentObj = JSON.parse(inputJSON);

contentObj.time = flowFile.getAttribute("timestamp");


outputStream.write(JSON.stringify(contentObj).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}));

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
}
```

getting error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/jdoodle.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class StreamCallback
 @ line 8, column 36.
   flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new 
                                      ^

1 error
```

Comment: that seems to be Javascript, not Groovy

Comment: can you help to find the groovy script to do the same

Comment: why you think this is javascript

Comment: `var flowFile = session.get();` Note `var`

Comment: Also, it looks like all the JavaScript examples here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: And nothing like the Groovy examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor (it's optimized for groovy lang) with this kind of code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

flowFile.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    def json = rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){ r-> new JsonSlurper().parse(r) }
    json.time = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", json.time).getTime()/1000
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){ w-> new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(w) }
}

REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

this code converts format of the field `time` with Date format to unix epoch time inside json content of flowfile.

Comment: Hi daggett Thanks for your response

Comment: getting some  error  : ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=c4849b42-0181-1000-9e76-01b5367ca62a] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Scriptffffffffd89aa9e8.var() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovySessionFile)

Comment: Sorry, should be `def` instead of `var`. Copy-paste issue.

Comment: Soory Daggett its work for me